# Как вывести ошибку метода VK Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь вывести ошибку вк на русском, есть ли какой то метод или модуль? Просто я пишу словами а нужен автоматизм.

Вот код:

```
vk.api.messages.removeChatUser({ chat_id: message.chatId, user_id: _chatsusers.vkid}).catch((e) => { return message.send(`⚠ Не удалось исключить пользователя из беседы.\nVk Error: Не получается исключить этого пользователя. Доступ запрещён. Возможно он создатель или администратор беседы.\nVK Api Error: ${e.message}`) }) // в _chatusers айдишник
```

Дополню, нашел код ошибки `e.code`, а так же нашел весь массив с ошибками, допустим код ошибки равен `"1"`, как найти что то в `{}`, если в нем:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "subcodes": {
      "too_many_communities": {
        "subcode": 1
      },
      "user_reached_linked_accounts_limit": {
        "subcode": 1000
      },
      "service_uuid_link_with_another_user": {
        "subcode": 1001
      }
    }
  },
  "errors": {
    "api_error_unknown": {
      "code": 1,
      "description": "Unknown error occurred",
      "global": true
    }
  }
} // Все ошибки не стал указывать.
```